# How to write on XLSX file using Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, xlsx, alasql

I need suggestion on how to make a XLSX file using (Javascript array or JSON) and Style Object. I am already using alasql for generating the XLS file. But on opening of that file some advisory message is coming (verify that the file is not corrupted...).

The code i am using is

```
 $scope.items = [{name: "nikki", sur: 1001, pos: '', data5 : "FSSS SDFGFD ",data6 : 323}]

 var mystyle = { sheetid: 'MyFile',
                 headers: true,
                 caption: {title:'Demo File'},
                 columns: [{columnid:'name',title:'Name' , width : 100},
                           {columnid:'sur',title:'Sur', width : 100},
                           {columnid:'pos',title:'Position', width : 100},
                           {columnid:'data5',title:'01/01/2017', width : 100},
                           {columnid:'data6',title:'02/01/2017', width : 100},
                 ], cells: {
                     0:{
                         3:{
                           style: 'background:rgb(155,194,230)'
                         },
                         4:{
                           style: 'background:rgb(155,194,230)'
                         }
                     }
                 }
              };

 $scope.exportData = function () {
        alasql('SELECT * INTO XLS("john.xls",?) FROM ?',[mystyle,$scope.items]);
    };
```

I tried with this code:

```
 alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("john.xlsx",?) FROM ?',[mystyle,$scope.items]);
```

**I am able to get the desired format but the style value is not setting. Please suggest some plugin or some code to achieve the desired result**.

working Fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0xnrq02/)

Comment: This example is not complete. In particular, there is no mention of styles anywhere. See [the stackoverflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information. Also, it seems very strange that you desire a plugin instead of writing code.

Comment: @phihag Edited !!

Comment: While the edit is indeed better, a *complete* example is one that can be run without any more modifications. This allows anybody to test solving the answer. You can use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) if you want to include libraries. Your example should also be *minimal*, i.e. the shortest code that reproduces the problem. For example, in this case your problem seems related to file generation, so a minimal example should not include any alasql code.

Comment: @phihag Added fiddle too!!!

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce your problem: XLSX works but is missing style, XLS fails (although LibreOffice can import the resulting file). The reason why using XLS fails is that the generated file is not an .xls file, but HTML with some custom XML tags interspersed.